# No field names CSV Reader Python UTF-8

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, field

So I'm trying to open and read csv file that has no field names.  Based on the research I've done, I'm pretty sure it's encoded in UTF-8.  My csv has this formatting:

```
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 
2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I use the following to open and read it:

```
def parseCSVCounter(csv_file):

with codecs.open(csv_file, "r", "utf-8-sig","strict", -1) as f:
    f = str(f)
    relayreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in relayreader:
        print(row)

        try:
            #row[0] = unicode(row[0], 'latin-1')
            counter(row)
            print('starting row..')

        except UnicodeDecodeError, e:
            print('something went wrong1')
            print e

        except Exception, e:
            print('something went wrong')
            print e
```

This generates

```
Starting Command..
['<']
something went wrong
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<'
['o']
something went wrong
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'o'
........
starting row..
['9']
starting row..
['3']
starting row..
['8']
starting row..
['2']
starting row..
['8']
starting row..
['>']
something went wrong
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '>'`
```

I cut this down to prove my point.  It seems that it's automatically generating field names for me.  With `csv.DictReader(fieldnames = 'foo')` I am able to specify field names in a sequence.  How do I get `csv.reader()` to ignore the lack of field names?

Comment: `>>> x = open('aaa', 'w')`
`>>> str(x)`
`"<open file 'aaa', mode 'w' at 0x01FC9860>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do *not* need to call `str(f)`; use the file object *directly*:

```
with codecs.open(csv_file, "r", "utf-8-sig", "strict") as f:
    relayreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

You are trying to read the output of `str(f)` as a CSV file instead, and that's a string of the form:

```
<open file '/path/to/file', mode 'rb' at 0x105f10d20>
```

You can see that from your error output; it is spelling out `<`, `o`, etc. all the way through to the memory address digits and the closing `>`.

Note that the `utf-8-sig` codec can handle a UTF-8-encoded [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to be present at the start of the file, but unless that BOM is expected to be there, the normal `UTF-8` codec will do just fine.